Not able to install npm packages when doing "npm install" but works with "npm init xyz"
Node version: 16.20.2
NPM version: 8.19.4
NVM version: 0.39.7
OS: Amazon Linux 2
When I try to create a new playwright project using npm init playwright@latest -- --ct, the packages are created and the package.json file is created. It gives warning that node version is not supported, but still runs flawlessly.
When I try to use the same package.json elsewhere but use npm install, it fails and exists saying rollup version error, expected 0.21.4 but received 0.18.4 (numbers are not accurate but yes, one is higher and the other is lower)
Why is this happening ? It's posing a problem because when working with git, npm install fails and I have to recreate the entire project using npm init.

Please, list the entire error instead of describing it. "When I try to use the same package.json elsewher" - please, provide it. Currently the problem is not reproducible.

This discrepancy is likely because the package-lock.json or previously cached modules contain versions that conflict with your intended updates or installations.
Why is this happening?

Cached Node Modules:

npm install uses the existing node_modules and package-lock.json.
If there are version conflicts between dependencies in package-lock.json and your local environment, errors occur.


Project Initialization Differences:

npm init playwright@latest sets up a fresh project environment every time, automatically fetching and resolving the correct dependencies.
This means it ignores the previous cache or package-lock.json, ensuring a clean installation.


Node Version Incompatibility:

Playwright and many packages have dependencies that work best with specific Node.js versions.
Your npm init playwright@latest even warns about the Node version incompatibility but still manages to work because it creates a fresh environment.



Solution
1. Clear Cache
First, clear the npm cache to ensure no remnants of old installations remain.
npm cache clean --force

2. Delete Old Files
Remove the node_modules folder and package-lock.json to get a clean slate.
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json

If you're on Windows (PowerShell):
rm -r node_modules
rm package-lock.json

3. Reinstall Dependencies
Run npm install to reinstall the dependencies fresh.
npm install

4. Update Rollup (If Applicable)
If Rollup version issues persist, manually install the correct version:
npm install rollup@latest --save-dev

Or, if you need a specific version:
npm install rollup@0.21.4 --save-dev

5. Verify Node Version Compatibility
Check your Node version and upgrade it if necessary.
node -v
npm -v

If you find the Node version is outdated, upgrade it using NVM:
nvm install 20  # Or whichever version you'd prefer
nvm use 20

Then, reinstall npm:
npm install -g npm

6. Clean Project Installation (Recommended)
As a last resort, recreate the project setup:
npm init playwright@latest -- --ct


is this an ai generated answer?
